# Use the same component instance on different pages

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I would like to find a solution to use the same component instance multiple times, on different pages but **without creating a new instance for each render**.
Each page must use the first initialized instance of the component. In few words, reuse the previously rendered component.

My goal is to display a map and draw a route on it with the current GPS position, which is updated in real time. This map is displayed on different size, on different locations / screens.

The problem is that this component must :

- be displayed on several pages independently
- not be rendered several times
- must be initialized only once

Example:

[image: app design]

Component A is initialized on screen 1. Then, we navigate on the screen 2, which must display Component A too. **But the particularity is that we must reuse the Component A on his exact previous state like it was on the screen 1 (with the view rendered, his states etc.)**.

For now, the component is always rendered on each screen once (standard behavior).

I tried hooks like useContext, useMemo but I cannot make it working like I want.

I tried to instantiate Component A on the Navigator (react-navigation) and passing Component A as parameter of the views.

I've made too some attempts with library like react-native-portal but nothing relevant.

Do you guys have a brillant idea?

Comment: Can you say more about why you only want the component rendered once, and how it's used? You could render the component in an overlay that goes over all your screens, if that would work for your layout.

Comment: @Abe thanks for answering. From my point of view, the overlay is not the solution because we need that component is displayed on several screens and included on the page view (and will be displayed on different placements, with different sizes). Right now, by navigating on screens, the view is rerender on each screen displayed. I'll try to add a schema on the original post.

Comment: Thanks for posting more information, that helps. Since it needs to be rendered differently on different pages, it will be a lot easier to render it multiple times. Do you have any way to save and load the map's state? If you can save the state in a central way, you won't have to worry about rendering multiple times.

Comment: Interesting, that could be a workaround for the map information indeed, but I have the feeling that there is no way to keep the component initialized and the map loaded over the other pages, each page are initializing the component itself and cannot reuse the previously one. That's how react works. Tho, your response answers partially to our needs :) thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: If it must be the same instance, you could render it in an overlay, and pass its position and size from each screen it's used on. If the screens are scrollable, you could even move the overlay with the scroll amount.